# What's the difference between <c t="str"> and <c><is> in Office Open XML?

Tags: excel, openxml, openxml-sdk, xlsx, spreadsheetml

What's the difference between these two Office Open XML fragments?

```
<c r="A2" t="str">
  <v>btyler</v>
</c>
```

and

```
<c r="B2">
  <is><t>btyler</t></is>
</c>
```

*note: The second sample I created manually based on the spec, the first is from an actual Excel workbook.*

Both seem valid and pretty much identical according to the spec, so I'm wondering why there is `t="str"` when `<is>` seemingly does the same thing.  When does Excel choose to use one over the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation at [18.18.11 ST_CellType](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-376,%20Third%20Edition,%20Part%201%20-%20Fundamentals%20And%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.zip):

> str (String) Cell containing a formula
>   string.

So you would only use your first example if a formula was in the `<x:v>` element.

The second one is used for inline strings and the `<x:c>` element should have a `t` attribute of `'inlineStr'`.  This will just be rich text that will be outputted and not stored in the sharedstring table.

So your first one would be valid like this:

```
<x:c r="C6" s="1" vm="15" t="str">
   <x:f>CUBEVALUE("xlextdat9 Adventure Works",C$5,$A6)</x:f>
   <x:v>2838512.355</x:v>
</x:c>
```

Your second one would be valid like this:

```
<x:c r="B2" t="inlineStr">
   <is><t>btyler</t></is>
</c>
```